# Jest for ReactJS test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following test for my React component

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;


describe('Navigation', function() {
var Navigation = require('../js/components/Navigation');
jest.dontMock('../js/components/Navigation.js');


 var NavElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Navigation items={[{ title: 'test' }, { title: 'test' }]} />
  );

  var items = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(NavElement, 'li');


  it('renders each item as a li', function() {
    expect(items.length).toEqual(2);


  });


});
```

Here is the React Component

```
'use strict'
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;



var Navigation = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
            <header>
            <ul>
            <li><Link to="clusters">Clusters</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="dependencies">Dependencies</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="components">Components</Link></li>
            </ul>
            </header>
            <RouteHandler />
            </div>
            );
        }
    });
    module.exports = Navigation;
```

BUt the test fails with the following error

```
- Expected 0 to equal 2.
        at jasmine.buildExpectationResult (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:80:44)
        at Object.eval (src/main/__tests__/app-test.js:23:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine-pit.js:35:32)
        at jasmine2 (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:253:7)
        at Test.run (node_modules/jest-cli/src/Test.js:44:12)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 1.518s)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `jest.dontMock` *after* you require the module. You must dot it *before* or your module will still be mocked: you will obtain a dummy component that does not implement any logic.

Also, while it is not the topic of your question, I do not think your component is doing what you want it to do. The provided `items` property is not used at all by your component. Currently, your component will always be rendered with the 3 `<li>` you defined in his rendered function. I would suggest you to have a quick look at the react tutorial and in particular [how to use props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#using-props).